# Storyboard UIViewControllers are too big for iPhone screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode6, interface-builder

Whenever I create a new project and select the single view application, the UIViewControllers are too big for any iphone emulator. How can the view controllers be resized to properly fit onto the screen? and how do I begin to make the interface be consistent across multiple devices with different resolutions?

Comment: In the simulated metrics, you can adjust the screen size as per your needs.

Comment: Yes, the screen is big. I am suspecting it is a controller for iPad? anyhow, I was able to select which device the storyboard would pertain to either iPhone or iPad, was that feature removed? Since I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Attributes Inspector -> Select a View Controller -> In the simulated metrics ,change the size.

You can choose the size you need.

Answer (score 0):

You talking about `Size Classes` technology, when you create universal layout for all kind of devices. You can switch between exact models of devices to adjust `UIViewController` size that you see.

However, if you wish to change the size manually, switch to `Size Inspector` and set `Simulated Size` to `Freeform` and enter values manually

Comment: I navigated to the simulated metric section within the inspector area and switch 'inferred ' to 'iPhone 5' and the view controller did resize, do you know if I have to define the same layout for all iOS devices I want to support? or is there a way to systematically define it. Thanks

Comment: @Alan I'm not sure for 100% that I understand what did you ask, but simulated metrics is only modifying appearance of that particular view in the Xcode, in runtime it will adapt for current running device. And if you want to change this parameter for all controllers, you need to do it manually, because by defaul it is inferred

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the auto-layout and constraints to make the objects on the View Controller sit correctly